# "Sandbox access violation" error in Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I got this odd error in my Stack Snippet today:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at "null".  Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag.

It happens when trying to run the snippet in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35529911/1) of mine. I removed the snippet and replaced it with plain code + [JSFiddle link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35529911/1), but what's up with that? Another answer to the question includes a working snippet. Maybe it's jQuery 1.11.1 vs 2.1.1?

I've included the snippet below for testing.

I'm using Chrome 48.0.2564.116 on Ubuntu.

```js
        $("#click").click(
            function fadeIn() {
                $("p:hidden").first().fadeIn("slow", fadeIn);

            }
        );
```

```css
p {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<button id="click">click</button>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
```

Comment: It seems to be something jQuery does that causes this warning.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, the iframe in which we execute users scripts is sandboxed. What jQuery does is, it creates another utility iframe **inside** our sandboxed iframe, which it uses to determine the value of an elements display property. The exception is thrown when jQuery tries to access contents of the inner iframe.

[image: boom]

So it looks like Chrome thinks that the utility iframe should be sandboxed from its parent iframe.

Relevant w3c example: https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#example-6dd42711

Setting `allow-same-origin` on our iframe would fix this, but discussing it internally, since it's [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - [How is my browser protected from XSS in Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/how-is-my-browser-protected-from-xss-in-stack-snippets/240215#240215)

Stay tuned for updates.

Comment: For how long should we stay tuned?