# Why are we disallowed to use HTML5 local storage on code snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I attempted to post the following code snippet using HTML5 local storage, but I receive:

> Submit {   "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the
>   'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and
>   lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",   "filename":
>   "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 27,   "colno": 23 }

Here is the jsfiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/jvso1Lcc/22/

Below is the snippet:

```js
function reload() {
 localStorage.setItem('selectedVal',$('#mySelect').val());
  location.reload(true);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var selectedVal = localStorage.getItem('selectedVal');
    if (selectedVal){
       $('#mySelect').val(selectedVal)
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='mySelect'>
 <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
<button onclick="reload()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is not a bug, it's how JavaScript works in a sandboxed environment.

Comment: so how do I get away with it in jsfiddle is that not a sandboxed environment?

Comment: Because the `<iframe>` on JSFiddle has the `allow-same-origin` flag in the `sandbox` attribute.

Comment: could SO do the same?

Comment: You might want to wait on accepting an answer I'm [not entirely sure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets/345386#comment456331_345386) if the reasoning for it not being allowed that I gave is correct.

Comment: ok I unaccepted it.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I'd recommend reading [Minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/) article that explains one approach to how in features are implemented. Your question is likely asking for opposite of what reality is - feature is not there because it is not implemented rather than taken away.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317509/247702) a dev mentions that it's by design but that they'd discuss it internally. The post links to [a detailed explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240215/167646): *"The framed document is loaded into a unique origin, which means that all same-origin checks will fail; unique origins match no other origins ever, not even themselves. Among other impacts, this means that the document has no access to data stored in any origin’s cookies or any other storage mechanisms (DOM storage, Indexed DB, etc.)."*

Comment: I trust SO to run scripts on my machine.  I don't trust you (generic you as in any poster not a personal thing).  If I accidentally hit the button to run your code somehow, I want to minimize the ways you can attack my box.  Truthfully I think the run snippet feature is a bad idea for security and ought to be removed, I will never purposely run a script from an unknown user.

Comment: @GabeSechan: so SO could have a warning on "Run Snippet"? We are here to fix code problems and we are advised to post code here in snippets instead of JSFiddle. The same fool that will allow malicious code to run when clicking "Run Snippet" will be fooled when directed to JSFiddle from SO.

Comment: @mplungjan Posting code is so you can read it.  There's no way in hell I'm running code.  Run snippet should be removed for security reasons, there is no good reason to have it.  If someone really wants to run the code, they can copy paste it in their javascript console.  But if for some reason I do click it by accident, I want the highest level of sandboxing possible.

Comment: Or have an option for butterfingers to remove the run snippet. I have no problems except when I try to help people and am blocked from doing so

Comment: @GabeSechan and how would one "accidently" press "Run code snippet" button? Paranoid people can easily hide the button with adblock extensions that they already are using.

Comment: @vanowm You never accidentally click on things?  Especially on mobile, where I rarely manage to hit the right link in a list, about 30% of the time I hit the one above or below.  I don't think a day goes by when I don't accidentally click on something.  I have never correctly clicked on a reddit link on mobile without zooming in.  And I'm not wasting my time to adblock remove anything.  Not to mention its a lawsuit waiting to happen-  if my machine becomes compromised due to code hosted on a site, I am contacting my lawyer.

Comment: I don't recall ever accidently clicking giant "Run code snippet" button, even on mobile...

Comment: Congratulations.  I know I have.  I doubt I'm the only one.  It's a horrible and insecure idea, and should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use local storage requires `allow-same-origin`.

(I'm not sure at all if the rest of this answer is correct.)

But `allow-same-origin` combined with the also necessary `allow-scripts` creates a security risk, as [detailed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes):

> When the embedded document has the same origin as the main page, it is strongly discouraged to use both `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` at the same time, as that allows the embedded document to programmatically remove the sandbox attribute. Although it is accepted, this case is no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute.

I'm sure it also introduces many other vulnerabilities, although I don't know much about the topic.

So that won't be happening.

JSFiddle has much looser sandboxing restrictions and takes a more open approach that is appropriate for a site like JSFiddle but not for a site like SO.

Comment: I don't think that warning would apply here: the embedded document is on a different origin (`stacksnippets.net`) than the main page (`stackoverflow.com`).

Comment: @JeremyBanks The snippets are hosted from that domain, but from looking at the HTML for the snippet on this page, there doesn't appear to be an "embedded document" other than that one `<iframe>` for the snippet code.

Comment: Can SO not just have a warning on "Run Snippet"? We are here to fix code problems and we are advised to post code here in snippets instead of JSFiddle. The same fool that will allow malicious code to run when clicking "Run Snippet" will be fooled when directed to JSFiddle from SO.